# Проблема с удалением приложения

Tags: windows, windows-10, sublime-text

Всем привет! Возникла проблема при удалении sublime text из компьютера, выходит ошибка. Помогите пожайлуста!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут 3 варианта:

1. Уже удалил Sublime Text
2. Проверь путь D:\Sublime Text3 посмотри имеется ли там файл unins000.exe или похожий, запусти и удали через него
3. Установи утилиту по удалению софта и удаляй через него

Comment: я уже удалил sublime text но почему тогда он присутствует в приложениях

Comment: удалил как положено? через инсталлятор? если да, тогда 3 вариант для тебя, бывает такое к несчастью...

Comment: полно бесплатных утилит зачистки записей/файлов, оставшихся от некорректно удаленного ПО в WIndows: Revo Uninstaller, IObit Uninstaller, etc.

Comment: нет я забомбил и удалил через корзину, все файлы перетащил туда и удалил